# Change value of table field when value of another field was changed in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table in oracle database that has two fields: `status` and `notes`. There are only 3 actual values for `status` field: `active, not-active, removed`.

- When `status` is `active`,  by default `notes` field has nothing in it.
- If `status` is changed to `not-active`, `notes` will have value entered.
  by the user
- If `status` is changed back to `active`, I need `notes` field value removed.

I've never used triggers before so for me it's a bit complicated but here is what I have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_notes
AFTER UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF status = 'Active' THEN UPDATE table1 SET notes = '';
END IF;
END;
```

But it fails.. What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use an `update` statement, just assign the value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_notes
BEFORE UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.status = 'Active' THEN 
     :new.notes = null;
  END IF;
END;
```

<sup>Btw: tables have *columns*, not "fields"</sup>

Comment: Now I've something totally different : 04084. 00000 -  "cannot change NEW values for this trigger type"
*Cause:    New trigger variables can only be changed in before row
           insert or update triggers.
*Action:   Change the trigger type or remove the variable reference

Comment: @user3065540: sorry I didn't see you were using  a `AFTER` trigger. Of course you need to use a `BEFORE` trigger (see my edit)

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name! This one: CREATE TRIGGER update_notes
BEFORE UPDATE ON VP_DET
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.VP_STATUS = 'Active' THEN 
     :new.VP_STATUS_NOTES := '';
  END IF;
END;   worked!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try below..

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_notes     
AFTER UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEING
  IF :NEW.status = 'Active' THEN
     :NEW.notes = '';
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: There is no `inserted` in Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You r right my dear.. I ma just change my quote. so if any one review this blog then they didn't confused.